# Flutter bluetooth device scan data

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth

I have an application that connects to a bluetooth device to read the scan. It returns an object like :

```
late StreamSubscription<List<int>> _lastValueSubscription;
_lastValueSubscription = characteristic.lastValueStream.listen((value) {
  _value = value;
  String skuCode = String.fromCharCodes(_value);
}
```

The skuCode is not a valid string. It reads like a string, prints like a string but when you hover over it, it has no type. Also, when passed to hive as a filter, it returns nothing. However, when i manually type a string, it shows the data.

Comment: What exactly returns nothing? I am not seeing a return value from the callback. If you istantiate skuCode inside the callback you need to return it. Or better instantiate it outside the callback and assign the value insude the callback.
Another option could be making the widget you are using the subscription in a StatefulWidget with an skucode state and call setState from the inside of the callback.

Comment: @AlbertoL.Bonfiglio when i click on skuCode, it has the string but no type, when you hover over skuCode variable, its grey in color telling the conversion was done but there is a type ambiguity

Comment: What is the value you are getting in the subscription? is it a UTF8 or 16?
Also you don't need to add it to _value. you can just pass value directly to the function.

Comment: var _ = characteristic.lastValueStream.listen((value) {
      String skuCode = String.fromCharCodes(value);
      if (skuCode.isNotEmpty) {
        takeSkuToDetail(skuCode);
      }
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    });

Comment: That code doesn't make much sense. Where are you declaring mounted? Plus are you sure the value is a valid List<int>? If you want set up a Zapp sandbox and i can help you there.

Comment: I am new to flutter, my code is a copy from flutter_bluetooth_plus, it returns as a List<int> from a barcode scan device, but the result converting to a string is messed up, it should be simple but the type changes, so i am guessing there is something wrong with the conversion which makes it string but type ambiguity

Comment: Post the actual value of the byteArray so i can try it. You could also try with  utf8.decode(byteArray) to see if it returns an error.

Comment: var List<Int> = [70, 85, 82, 73, 83, 76, 65, 78, 71, 68, 66, 78, 84,13]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256506/discussion-between-alberto-l-bonfiglio-and-ramiz-girach).